# Type hinting an interface using a string value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm trying to figure out a way of typehinting dynamically in Typescript. Depending on the object I receive, I want to create an object of a certain interface type (based on some property in the received object). Here's a very basic example:

```
interface ITest {
  location: string;
  record: Record<string,unknown>[];
}


const test = {
  location: "Victoria",
  record: [
    {
      name: "matt",
      age: 29,
      is_single: false,
    }
  ]
};


if(test.location === "Victoria") {
  const interfaceName = 'ITest';

  newMessage: interfaceName = test;

}
```

With this example in mind I'm wondering how to correctly type hint `ITest` using the string value `interfaceName`.

I do know that simply passing the string value of the interface name of the interface is incorrect, but that's sort of the desired effect. I'm not an expert at Typescript and would appreciate some help!

Comment: You can't use types at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
type ITest = {
  location: 'Victoria';
  record: Record<string, SomeType>[];
} | {
  location: 'Georgia';
  record: Record<string, OtherType>[];
}
```

```
if (test.location === "Victoria") {
  // `test.record` is of type `Record<string, SomeType>[]` in this block
} else {
  / `test.record` is of type `Record<string, OtherType>[]` in this block
}
```